# Set network connection to offline of CefSharp via code

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium, cefsharp, offline-mode

Exists there a method to set the network connection of CefSharp to offline.
I want to use CefSharp just as a renderer for html tables in WinForms and dont want any connections to the internet by chromium.

Maybe there exist a way to set the devTools Network state to offline via code but i couldnt find any functions to do so.

Comment: There is no such method. If you only load local html and it never makes a request to the internet, then you shouldn't have a problem. What requests do you think `CEF` will make exactly?

Comment: I'am not sure if chromium has some internal calls to google services or something like that. Eg:

_However, Chromium includes many features that depend on Google’s servers, and they’re enabled by default. You’ll see these features listed on the Settings page. They include a web service that helps fix mistyped web addresses, a prediction service, Google’s anti-phishing feature, and more._
src: [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/202825/what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-chromium-and-chrome/)

Comment: Your just assuming all those features exist? `CefSharp` is based on the `Chromium Embedded Framework`, which uses the `Chromium Content API`. It's the framework for creating a browser, there is no settings page, there is no `anti-phising feature`, no feature for fixing urls. Use `CefSharp`, analyse the network traffic it generates, then see if you need to take action.....

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/developers/content-module